# Что такое переменная _unit в файле автоматических тестов от работодателя?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, karma

Хочу попасть на работу в одну компанию и мне выслали тестовое задание следующего характера: сделать API для аутентификации. И вместе с этим скинули тесты, которые это приложение должно пройти. Очень долго мучался с тем, что б вытащить `token` из обьекта `request`. Вроде домучал, но теперь выдает ошибку что `_user` не определен. Вот код тестов и файла сервера:

```
'use strict'

let assert = require('chai').assert
let request = require('supertest-as-promised')

let app = require('../../app')
let email = 'integration_test_' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + '@wartech.ua'
let password = 'test'
let name = 'My name'

describe('Authentication Controller', () => {

  it('should register a new user and return token', () => {
    let _token = null;

    return request(app)
      .post('/api/register')
      .send({ email, password, name })
      .expect(201)
      .then((data) => {
        _token = data.body.token;
        assert.ok(_token);
      });
  });

  it('should login existing User', () => {
    let _token = null;
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/login')
      .send({ email, password })
      .expect(200)
      .then((data) => {
        _token = data.body.token;
        assert.ok(_token);
      });
  });

  it('should return an error bad request if email is used', () => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/register')
      .send({ email, password, name})
      .expect(400);
  });

  it('should return an error bad request if email isn\'t specified', () => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/register')
      .send({ password, name })
      .expect(400);
  });

  it('should return an error bad request if password isn\'t specified', () => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/register')
      .send({ email, name })
      .expect(400);
  });
});

describe('Profile controller', () => {

  let _token = null;

  before(() => {
    return request(app)
      .post('/api/login')
      .send({ email, password })
      .then((data) => {
        _token = data.body.token;
        assert.ok(_token);
      });
  });

  it('should fetch the profile info of existing user', () => {
    return request(app)
      .get('/api/profile')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token)
      .expect(200)
      .then((data) => {
        assert.equal(data.body.email, _user);
      });
  });

  it('should return an error when token is not specified', () => {
    return request(app)
      .get('/api/profile')
      .expect(401);
  });
});
```

А приложение выглядит следующим образом:

```
'use strict';
//require packages
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let morgan = require('morgan');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let config = require('./config');
let User = require('./models/user');
let router = express.Router();
//connect database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
app.set('superSecret', config.secret);
//configure express
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/api', router);

//index route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello');
});
//user create route
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {

    //search if user with this email exists
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (user) {
            //provide status response if true
            res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'User with this email already exists'
            });
        } else {
            //if email isn't provided - response with status code 400
            if (!req.body.email) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Email wasn\'t provided'
                })
            } else {
                //if everything is ok create user and save
                User.create({
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: req.body.password,
                    name: req.body.name
                }, function(err, newUser) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        // create a token
                        let token = jwt.sign(newUser, app.get('superSecret'), {
                            expiresIn: "24h", // expires in 24 hours
                            issuer: newUser.name
                        });
                        // return the information including token as JSON
                        res.status(201).json({
                            success: true,
                            message: 'Register successful, token sent',
                            token: token
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

router.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    // find the user
    User.findOne({
        email: req.body.email
    }, function(err, user) {

        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        } else if (user) {

            // check if password matches
            if (user.password != req.body.password) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
            } else if (!req.body.email) {
                //check if email provided
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. No email was provided. ' });
            } else if (!req.body.email == user.email) {
                //check if email matches
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. E-mail doesn\'t match. ' });
            }

            // if user is found and password is right
            // create a token
            let token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                expiresIn: "24h" // expires in 24 hours
            });

            // return the information including token as JSON
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                token: token
            });
        }



    });
});
router.get('/profile', checkToken, function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        name: req.decoded._doc.name,
        email: req.decoded._doc.email
    })
});

function checkToken(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers['authorization']);
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['authorization'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {

        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        });

    } else {
        console.log('token not found');

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(401).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });

    }

}

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server started');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Помогите мне понять как определить эту переменную? Я хоть убей не могу ничего придумать. Тесты, как вы поняли, трогать мне нельзя. Впервые работаю с аутентификацией на токенах, буду рад помощи или совету.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, с другой стороны, раз ошибка в тестах, то может работа не такая уж и престижная?

Comment: Ну а что касается переменной `_user`, так она действительно не определена. Либо работодатель проверяет вас на внимательность, либо вы не верно скопировали код тестов. А еще есть вероятность, что работодатель вообще не достоен вашего времени (ведь тесты некорректны и без магии не будут проходить).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, (1) Какая внимательность, если интерпретатор сам сдаст все явки? (2) Сложно скопировать код **до** и **после** определения, но **без** него. А если это глобальная переменная...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54340/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-other).

Comment: Код я не копировал, мне дали сразу папку уже с package.json и папкой с тестами, так что сделать какие-то изменения я не мог.

Comment: Что в секции `scripts` вашего `package.json`?